# Only <tr> tag is missing using requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a simple web scrapping tool.
Right now I'm having an issue extracting data from each row because `<tr>` header is missing.
(Only `<tr>` header is missing, and `<\tr>` header is still there)

Below is my code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://companiesmarketcap.com/dow-jones/largest-companies-by-market-cap/"
data = requests.get(url).text
print(data)
```

It's missing a  header, and only  exists for each row

```html
<tbody>
((THERES SUPPOSED TO BE A <tr> TAG HERE))))!!!
<td class="fav"><img alt="favorite icon" src="/img/fav.svg?v2" data-id="2"></td>
</td><td class="rank-td td-right" data-sort="1">1
</td><td class="name-td">
<div class="logo-container"><img loading="lazy" class="company-logo" alt="Apple logo" src="/img/company-logos/64/AAPL.png" data-img-path="/img/company-logos/64/AAPL.png" data-img-dark-path="/img/company-logos/64/AAPL.D.png"></div>
<div class="name-div"><a href="/apple/marketcap/"><div class="company-name">Apple</div>
<div class="company-code"><span class="rank d-none"></span>AAPL</div>
</a></div></td><td class="td-right" data-sort="2891576508416">$2.891 T</td><td class="td-right" data-sort="18592">$185.92</td><td data-sort="18" class="rh-sm"><span class="percentage-green"><svg class="a" viewBox="0 0 12 12"><path d="M10 8H2l4-4 4 4z"></path></svg>0.18%</span></td><td class="p-0 sparkline-td red"><svg><path d="M0,21 5,18 10,22 15,14 20,16 25,12 30,8 35,14 40,11 45,3 50,3 55,4 60,8 65,6 70,10 75,11 80,13 85,13 90,14 95,14 100,13 105,16 110,16 115,31 120,34 125,39 130,41 135,31 140,32 145,30 150,31 155,30" /></svg></td><td> <span class="responsive-hidden">USA</span></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you!

I tried following

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table")
# print(table)
rows = table.find_all("tr")
```

but it doesn't work, because again, `<tr>` header is missing

Comment: Is the `<tr>` header present in the actual html?  Sometimes pages have wrong html.

Comment: Yep, structure is like <tbody> <tr> .... </tr> in actual html page.

Comment: I think this is because you're using `requests` to fetch the page content, which does not allow the page to execute javascript.

Comment: @SnowHana don't spam question's tags:) + hint: when writing a post containing different languages (HTML, python, ...) to activate the syntax highlight add the language name after the first triple `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the HTML of the page is malformed. So to parse it like a browser does use `html5lib` parser:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://companiesmarketcap.com/dow-jones/largest-companies-by-market-cap/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html5lib')

for tr in soup.table.select('tr'):
    tds = [t for td in tr.select('td') if (t:=td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))]
    if len(tds) == 6:
        print(*tds, sep='\t')
```

Prints:

```
1       Apple AAPL      $2.891 T        $185.92 0.18%    USA
2       Microsoft MSFT  $2.887 T        $388.47 1.00%    USA
3       Visa V  $542.91 B       $264.17 0.05%    USA
4       JPMorgan Chase JPM      $488.72 B       $169.05 0.73%    USA
5       UnitedHealth UNH        $482.35 B       $521.51 3.37%    USA
6       Walmart WMT     $434.31 B       $161.32 0.13%    USA
7       Johnson & Johnson JNJ   $390.91 B       $162.39 0.77%    USA
8       Procter & Gamble PG     $354.94 B       $150.60 0.06%    USA

...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is header above tbody (table > thead). You don't need header if you want to extract data in the table.
Just refer to the "loc", which is CSS selector and can be used in BS4 select, in the following xml to extract the data in the table:

```xml
  <actions>
    <action_goto url="https://companiesmarketcap.com/dow-jones/largest-companies-by-market-cap/" />
    <action_loopineles>
      <element loc="table.dataTable > tbody > tr:not([class*=sort])" />
        <action_extract tabname="dat_00000000000012ab">
          <column_element colname="c01" nickname="rank">
            <element loc="td.rank-td" />
            <elecontent_text top="true" />
          </column_element>
          <column_element colname="c02" nickname="name">
            <element loc="td.name-td div.company-name" />
          </column_element>
          <column_element colname="c03" nickname="marketCap">
            <element loc="tr > td:nth-child(4)" />
          </column_element>
          <column_element colname="c04" nickname="price">
            <element loc="tr > td:nth-child(5)" />
          </column_element>
          <column_element colname="c05" nickname="today">
            <element loc="tr > td:nth-child(6)" />
          </column_element>
          <column_element colname="c06" nickname="country">
            <element loc="tr > td:nth-child(8)" />
          </column_element>
        </action_extract>
    </action_loopineles>
  </actions>
```

Sample of extracted data:
[image]

Comment: Please use Adrej Kesely's new answer, it's more suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to identify patterns that represent rows or cells within the table.

For example:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

One way is to use regular expressions to find td elements within the table and extract data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).